# Syntax explanation

Tags: c++

In code:

```
struct tagPaint
{
}Paint,//<<<--------------what's this (Paint)?
*pPaint;//<<<-------------and this(*pPaint)?
```

I mean do I declare variable with name Paint of type tagPaint and pointer called pPaint to tagPaint?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paint is a variable of type tagPaint. pPaint is  a pointer to type tagPaint. If you want them to define types, then you need:

```
typedef struct tagPaint {
   ...
}  Paint, * pPaint;
```

but this is C usage - you should not be writing code like that in C++. and even in C, defining a type that hides the fact that something is a pointer is considered bad style.

Answer (score 5):

You are allowed to declare and define a `struct` or `class` in a declaration of a variable of that type.

So, that declaration defines three symbols: `tagPaint` (which can also be called `struct tagPaint` in C style), `Paint` which is a `tagPaint`, and `pPaint` which points to a `tagPaint`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the code that you've actually posted `Paint` is declared as a `struct tagPaint` and `pPaint` is a pointer to a `struct tagPaint`.

Are you sure you haven't missed a `typedef` from before `struct`? Given the names, defining `typedef`s would be far more usual.

Answer (score 1):

`Paint` is an instance of `struct tagPaint`, and `pPaint` is a pointer to `struct tagPaint`.

The structure needs the `typedef` keyword preceding it in order to use `Paint` as a type, and `pPaint` as a pointer to type `Paint`.

Answer (score 0):

You declare both of them :)

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring both of them.  You can declare primitives the same way:

```
int a, b, c, d;
```

But instead of the int type you're declaring an instance of tagPaint along with a pointer to a tagPaint.